# How to lodge disagreement with certain Review Test fails?

Tags: feature-request

In Review, I usually pass the tests when they occur.

The most common cause of failing is that I add a comment to a first-timer's question asking for clarification about what their goal was, or some such.

So then after the fail, there is no way to lodge my disagreement with the test.

Why does the review test fail as I try to comment on crappy questions in the first place?

I have no idea what those tests are for.

And when I fail one yet disagree with the decision, the learning experience is directly tied to the testing process and nothing to do with Ubuntu.

This seems very counterproductive.  And just annoying enough that I sought out this `meta` to say something about it.

Who decides this, anyway?

### SUGGESTION:  Instead of just being able to click on "I Understand" there should be a second button for "I Disagree"

Comment: Don't worry about it. The only reason the tests exist is to discourage "robo-reviewing": people who just blindly click through things in the queues to get a badge. Yes, people are strange. But there's no penalty for failing one or anything, we've all done so because they're not always well chosen. Just shrug and keep reviewing.

Comment: TNX, @terdon.  Appreciate it.

Comment: @terdon If you fail too many audits don't you get banned from reviewing for a few days?

Comment: @ubashu not if you fail one. You need to fail a lot, it really doesn't happen often. Failing the odd audit is nothing to worry about. The system is designed to catch people who just click blindly without paying attention.

Comment: I wish there were a way to encourage people reviewing First Posts to do *something* :( Thanks for reviewing and sorry you failed an audit for trying to do something helpful

Comment: It would be nice if it was smart enough to notice a detailed comment as being valid or at least debatable.  Thank you for the explanation.